# Текст на странице «Как задавать вопросы»

Tags: обсуждение

Страница
https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
содержит текст, явно относящийся к какому-то сайту про программированию. Надо бы исправить. Давайте обсудим? Можно, например, для начала взять текст отсюда: https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic и перевести на русский.

Comment: Смежный вопрос http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16/

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Спасибо, я его пропустил. Удалим этот вопрос? И что делать со справкой-то?

Comment: Вопрос можно отметить как дубликат. Справку необходимо создавать, а затем редактировать всем вместе! Других путей нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Я просто никогда справок не создавал в SE. Где это делается технически?

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ. Для создания правки необходимо создать вопрос на Мете, который будет содержать текст справки. Как только сообщество согласится, что описание достаточно хорошо, я добавлю его через специальный интерфейс (доступ к которому есть только у сотрудников компании).